# SharePoint Hybrid Configuration - Cloud Search Issue

Tags: 2019, hybrid-search

I am starting to use SharePoint hybrid configuration using ShP 2019 Ent with O365 ShP online (E3 plan) which went well so far, everything works except (Cloud) Search. For some reason I am not able to finish the Hybrid configuration wizard (or onboard script like PowerShell equivalent) and establish the connection between the two components. Both tools gives me slightly different result for which Google gives no clue how to solve (for now).

SharePoint Hybrid Configuration Wizard
[image]

Onboard-CloudHybridSearch
[image]

[image]
[image]

- Azure Active Directory PowerShell installed
- Microsoft Sign-In Assistant installed
- Connect-SPOservice with no issue opens connection
- Other hybrid services works (UPS, Metadata, Launcher...)
- iisreset(s), restarts done, all updates ins
- no proxy (netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie)
- LoopbackCache disabled
- no MFA
- PSconfig finished with no issue, ULS logs clean

The log: https://1drv.ms/t/s!Alq2_oJioYHRiJAy4KJ3xhuJ6lQx9Q?e=pKBXIU

[edit 03. 08. 2020]
I removed whole (cloud)search SA and started from scratch. Checked the rights, use the scripts, CloudSearch SA was created with no issue and at the end exactly the same error message appears. What changed? I have ULS logs full of object not found issues (for a registry key heading to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office Server\16.0\Search) and non-existed DB (Database with Id 07d3191a-af15-4547-bc71-355c5718be9a was not found in database collection. Returning null.) So it did not help me at all.

Maybe I miss something obvious here...
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Onboard-CloudHybridSearch says 'Internal server error'. Cloud you please check ULS-Log. Maybe the internal server error comes from your local farm, so we can track it. Post the log in your question.

Comment: For the connection to SPO, can you try a non-MFA'ed account? But Internal Server Error likely indicates the issue is service-side. You may want to open a support case with Microsoft.

Comment: @MHeld: ULS logs were nicely clean, except perflib issues in Event log nothing there either. Now I have some issues after original CloudSaearchSA was removed, check the update. But nothing relevant to original issue.

Comment: @Trevor Seward: there is no MFA configured